# Reading several arrays in a binary file with numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, io, binary

I'm trying to read a binary file which is composed by several matrices of float numbers separated by a single int. The code in Matlab to achieve this is the following:

```
fid1=fopen(fname1,'r');
for i=1:xx
    Rstart= fread(fid1,1,'int32');        #read blank at the begining
    ZZ1 = fread(fid1,[Nx Ny],'real*4');   #read z
    Rend  = fread(fid1,1,'int32');        #read blank at the end
end
```

As you can see, each matrix size is Nx by Ny. Rstart and Rend are just dummy values. ZZ1 is the matrix I'm interested in.

I am trying to do the same in python, doing the following:

```
Rstart = np.fromfile(fname1,dtype='int32',count=1)
ZZ1 = np.fromfile(fname1,dtype='float32',count=Ny1*Nx1).reshape(Ny1,Nx1)
Rend = np.fromfile(fname1,dtype='int32',count=1)
```

Then, I have to iterate to read the subsequent matrices, but the function **np.fromfile** doesn't retain the pointer in the file.

Another option:

```
with open(fname1,'r') as f:
   ZZ1=np.memmap(f, dtype='float32', mode='r', offset = 4,shape=(Ny1,Nx1))
   plt.pcolor(ZZ1)
```

This works fine for the first array, but doesn't read the next matrices. Any idea how can I do this?

I searched for similar questions but didn't find a suitable answer.

Thanks

Comment: `numpy.fromfile` also accepts a file object as first argument.

Comment: Perfect. That was exactly what I was looking for. Important to point that file should be opened in binary mode, e.g `fid=open(fname,'rb')` . Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way to read all your matrices in a single vectorized statement is to use a struct array:

```
dtype = [('start', np.int32), ('ZZ', np.float32, (Ny1, Nx1)), ('end', np.int32)]
with open(fname1, 'rb') as fh:
    data = np.fromfile(fh, dtype)
print(data['ZZ'])
```

Comment: Beautiful answer! I was not sure how composite dtype worked. Thank you.

Comment: The downside I think is that it loads all the arrays at once, which I should avoid with big files.

Comment: you can still add a count parameter to fromfile I think, no?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions for this problem.

The first one:

```
for i in range(x):
    ZZ1=np.memmap(fname1, dtype='float32', mode='r', offset = 4+8*i+(Nx1*Ny1)*4*i,shape=(Ny1,Nx1))
```

Where **i** is the array you want to get.

The second one:

```
fid=open('fname','rb')
for i in range(x):
    Rstart = np.fromfile(fid,dtype='int32',count=1)
    ZZ1 = np.fromfile(fid,dtype='float32',count=Ny1*Nx1).reshape(Ny1,Nx1)
    Rend = np.fromfile(fid,dtype='int32',count=1)
```

So as  morningsun points out, np.fromfile can receive a file object as an argument and keep track of the pointer. Notice that you must open the file in binary mode 'rb'.